# How can I speed the function on element-wise on two 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, vectorization

Assume I have a function that is defined for two float values, and this function is rather complex that is not easy to be modified. Now I have two same 2D arrays, say $X_{n \times m}, Y_{n \times m}$, I need to carry out the function on each element on the 2D array $x_{ij}, y_{ij}$. How can I speed this work with respect to the two for loops?

The following is the general code, in which the function has been simplified to be a summation:

```
def func(x, y):
     return x + y

X = np.random.rand(100, 100)
Y = np.random.rand(100, 100)

Z = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
       z = func(X[i, j], Y[i, j])
       Z[i, j] = z
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods

- 1. Using [numpy vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)
- 2. Using Numpy functions

**Method 1--Numpy Vectorize**

Provides 4X speed up (3.14 ms vs. 12.1 ms)

```
%%timeit

Z = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
       z = func(X[i, j], Y[i, j])
       Z[i, j] = z

12.2 ms ± 901 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Using Vectorize*

```
%%timeit

vec_func = np.vectorize(func)  # vectorized version of function

Z2 = vec_func(X, Y)            # use vectorized version on X, Y

3.14 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Method 2--Using Numpy vectorized functions**

If the more complex function can be done with [numpy functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html) such as add, subtract, sqrt, exp, etc.

- Provides ~775 speedup for simple function example (15.5 us vs. 12.1 ms)

*Code*

```
def func(X, Y):
    return np.add(X, Y)

%timeit Z3 = func(X, Y)

15.5 µs ± 1.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.vectorize` or use Python lists and floats instead of NumPy:

```
4.82 ms  original
1.78 ms  vectorized
2.02 ms  mapped
1.04 ms  mapped2
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPBjsIgEL3zFXMxgtt0td5M/I@qMQ0qdTGFEoob2593h4JaY/SwHFrKvJl57zE1rfup9fx6PYgSaiuPUvOKlme9TyBPYMUWBHCtYQnapJ2wdUPpbDpNAB@M9cGytiBBarBcH4WPxqxb8PQuiKvDyr4dzTcygdMWe4YNG6LW4QyxXX9shTtbDWtCPO9fsXfIvROHV@YRieTvqB7EaA8KBRQ35nMyt5a3dHPntJlgTky4JNCy7ZNif@RFd9LQPHV1JRtHGRa@74O87ROB7C2D/zXOsE4WGxFCSlsrcFIJ6UAqU1uH5Y3gjsQvfVamBd6gYEQ36PZtIpKBx0lke3tnQUJ/iT2jeL@R@gW@oCUkDxOEU3CoVf96jBFZfQrmGUYfJpKV/34YSYi4GCTn56jZTLdDD4m3pPR@lE1gZazUjtJyiILlEkINlvKq8nfTJxaPsZ1HUS/1/PKtldQ0mEkrrnYHvoCnHok3dyfscoZ/DXyjsnt6oDQepRnOQQNjGAF1MIGZmGNamRaF5koUBRsIYNfrHw)):

```
def original(func, X, Y):
    Z = np.zeros((100, 100))
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(100):
           z = func(X[i, j], Y[i, j])
           Z[i, j] = z
    return Z

def vectorized(func, X, Y):
    return np.vectorize(func)(X, Y)

def mapped(func, X, Y):
    return np.array([
        [*map(func, x, y)]
        for x, y in zip(X.tolist(), Y.tolist())
    ])

def mapped2(func, X, Y):
    return [
        [*map(func, x, y)]
        for x, y in zip(X2, Y2)
    ]


from timeit import repeat
import numpy as np

fs = original, vectorized, mapped, mapped2

def func(x, y):
     return x + y

X = np.random.rand(100, 100)
Y = np.random.rand(100, 100)
X2 = X.tolist()
Y2 = Y.tolist()

expect = fs[0](func, X, Y)
for f in fs:
    print((f(func, X, Y) == expect).all())

for _ in range(3):
    for f in fs:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: f(func, X, Y), number=10)) / 10
        print('%.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3), f.__name__)
    print()
```